# Akka.Net BecomeStacked/UnbecomeStacked behavior issue

Tags: behavior, akka.net

I have a problem with the behavior switch model.

I have a simple receive actor with 2 behaviors: `Ready` & `DoJob`.
The `Ready` one contains a message handler plus one instruction I need to be evaluated at each behavior switch (`cpt++`).

Below is the code of the actor:

```
public class BecomeUnbecome : ReceiveActor
{
    private int cpt=0;

    public BecomeUnbecome()
    {
       this.Become(this.Ready); 
    }

    public void Ready()
    {
        cpt++;

        Receive<BeginWork>(msg =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Go and work!");
            BecomeStacked(this.DoJob);
        });
    }

    public void DoJob()
    {
        Receive<Work>(msg =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start working...");
            Console.WriteLine($"Counter: {cpt}\nWork done\n");
            UnbecomeStacked();
        });
    }
}
```

The main code is:

```
int counter = 0;

while (counter < 10)
{
    actor.Tell(new BeginWork());
    actor.Tell(new Work());
    counter++;
}
```

The program execution shows `cpt++` in `Ready()` is evaluated once next to the call to `Become` in the constructor.

I cannot find any reasonable workaround to that.

Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: What do you mean by "reasonable workaround"? for what? what is your exectation?

Comment: My sole expectation is the instr `cpt++` to be executed at each UnbecomeStacked() call. The only workaround I found is to override UnbecomeStacked by calling in it Become(Ready) since there are only 2 behaviors but the sample I posted is a simple abstract of an application I'm working on with much more behaviors, inherited actor classes, ... and for which the worrkaround I found is absolutely not reasonable even ugly!